# Using if statement in Crystal Report command

Tags: sql, vb.net, if-statement, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that would read off of a different stored procedure depending on a parameter that comes in. What I have now fails out when making it in the wizard (complains that type1 is not a collumn). Both procedure use the included dates and return similar data.

```
    if {?Type} = "Type1"
   Begin
      exec storedprocedure1 
   End
else if {?Type} = "Type2"
   Begin
      exec storedprocedure2 
   End

      @DateFrom={?DateFrom}
     ,@DateTo={?DateTo}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the command as a script. You should be able to replace the parameters with the actual values and to run the script in your database.

if your database is sqlserver you need to use single quotes instead of double

```
if {?Type} = 'Type1'
      exec storedprocedure1 
else if {?Type} = Type2
      exec storedprocedure2
```

I am not sure what is the idea for the part with dates at the bottom, as it is now it will fail too.

Added on 4/7/2014

```
  if {?Type} = 'Type1'
      exec storedprocedure1 {?DateFrom}, {?DateTo}
  else if {?Type} = 'Type2'
      exec storedprocedure2 {?DateFrom}, {?DateTo}
```

Comment: both stored procedure had parameters for the dates.